# Combining two tables and highlighting certain values

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have got a variable list:

```
variableList = {"Personlichkeit d. Gründers", "Gechäftskonzept", "Arbeitseinsatz", "Führungskompetenz", "Sachkompetenz", "Finanzkraft", "BWL-Kenntnisse", "Schnelligkeit d. Umsetzung", "Gewinn", "Konkurrenz", "Wachstum"};
```

futher is my adjazenzmatrix looks like:

```
ErfolgsfaktorenEU={{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}
```

[image]

on tableform as shown:

```
TableForm[Map[{#, variableList[[#]]} &, Range[11]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"node nr.", "variables"}}]
```

so here all further codes that I gave:

```
TableForm[ErfolgsfaktorenEU, Range[11], TableHeadings -> Automatic]
g = AdjacencyGraph[ErfolgsfaktorenEU, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

    countLoopsWithVar[all_, var_] := Count[all, _?(MemberQ[Flatten[List @@@ #, 1], var] &)];

Map[countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #] &, Range[11]];

W = Total[ErfolgsfaktorenEU];

U = Map[Total, ErfolgsfaktorenEU];

\[CapitalDelta]Summe = U - W;

T = 1 - Min[\[CapitalDelta]Summe];
\[CapitalDelta] = T + \[CapitalDelta]Summe;

ProduktWert = Map[countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #] &, Range[11]]*\[CapitalDelta]*U

Rank = ProduktWert /. Thread[# -> Ordering[#, All, Greater]] &@ Union@ProduktWert;

prozent = N[ProduktWert/Total[ProduktWert]];

TableForm[Map[{#, variableList[[#]], countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #], U[[#]], 
W[[#]], \[CapitalDelta]Summe[[#]], \[CapitalDelta][[#]], ProduktWert[[#]],
Rank[[#]], 100*prozent[[#]]} &, Range[11]], TableHeadings -> {None, {"nr.", "Systemgrößen", "Anzahl der AW", "U",
 "W", "\[CapitalDelta]Summe", "\[CapitalDelta]", "Produkt", "RF", 
"%"}}, TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]

RelativeAnteile = Accumulate[Sort[100*prozent, Greater]];

maxProzent = Sort[prozent, Greater];

maxProdukWert = Sort[ProduktWert, Greater];

ABCZuordnung = Table[If[# <= 85, A, If[# <= 95, B, If[# <= 100, C]]] &[RelativeAnteile[[i]]], {i, Length[RelativeAnteile]}];

TableForm[{{"Produkt", "Umsatz", "Relative Anteile", 
"ABC-Zuordnung"}, {maxProdukWert, 100*maxProzent, RelativeAnteile,
 ABCZuordnung}}, TableSpacing -> {3, 3}, 
  TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] /. {A -> Style[A, Darker[Green]], B -> Style[B, Darker[Yellow]], C -> Style[C, Darker[Red]]}
```

all these codes gives me the true tables such like this pictures:

[image]

**Futher Question about it:**

Once in the ABC Analysis A Variable Nr. (row numbers) are determined as in the example given, 11, 6, 10, is analogous automatically the row values of lines 11, 6, 10 multiplies the "ErfogsfaktorenEU" Matrix 2 and as a new "ErfogsfaktorenEU "output matrix, such as issued in the last picture.

How can I realize this?

[image]

Comment: We need a lot more information about your problem to help you. We need to have all the quantities referenced in the code defined, and we to know how you want to combine your two tables; that is, describe how the combined table should look (an image of a drawing will do).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to add your ABC category as a separate column to a Table and highlight values. Here is a minimal example which does this:

```
relativeAnteile = Range[80, 100];
abcZuordnung = Table[If[# <= 85, A, If[# <= 95, B, 
               If[# <= 100, C]]]&[relativeAnteile[[i]]], {i, Length[relativeAnteile]}];

TableForm[{{"RelativeAnteile", "abcZuordnung"}, {relativeAnteile,abcZuordnung}}] /. {A -> 
Style[A, Darker[Green]],B -> Style[B, Orange], C -> Style[C, Magenta]}
```

The output table looks like this:

[image: combined table]

Comment: I have got a futher question about this, how can I edit a new Question from here?

Comment: you're welcome :) you might want to edit your post and update it with the new question? Or just post it in the comments.